# Extending class definition(defined in a library) in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, overloading

How to extend the definition of a class in Python 3.x ?

I have a library file graphics.py with a class Point defined in this way:

```
class Point(GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        GraphicsObject.__init__(self, ["outline", "fill"])
        self.setFill = self.setOutline
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def _draw(self, canvas, options):
        x,y = canvas.toScreen(self.x,self.y)
        return canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1,options)

    def _move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x = self.x + dx
        self.y = self.y + dy

    def clone(self):
        other = Point(self.x,self.y)
        other.config = self.config.copy()
        return other

    def __str__(self):
        return "Point({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def getX(self): return self.x
    def getY(self): return self.y
```

I wanted to extend the definition to define the sum of two points as a point with its x and y coordinates as sum of the x and y coordinates of given points respectively.

I tried

```
import graphics as gr

class Point(gr.Point):
    def __add__(self, another_point):
        return point((self.x+another_circle.x), (self.y+another_circle.y))
```

But this didn't helped ,It gave me a new class instead of extending the definition of gr.Point

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: if `gr.Point` comes from your code -- add `__add__` method to it instead of subclassing, if it originates from third-party library -- then you can subclass or write utility function for adding

Comment: @AzatIbrakov gr.Point originates from third-party library so can't it be done without subclass as it was preferred ?

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: I was contributing to one of my senior's project and he asked me for this if possible, anyways I guess I will make a subclass if this is not possible.

Comment: this is possible but not recommended